# Free/ Open source EPS editor for windows

Tags: inkscape, eps

I am honestly stoked that I can't find any after quite a few minutes googling!

Can someone suggest me a free/open source EPS editor that you don't need a PHD to install? does none exist? Everything seems to revolve around ghostscript, GIMP or other combination of tools

I don't want to have to convert my files to PDF or any other format, just editing.

Surely such program must exist?

I tried a few like libreoffice draw and inkscape and none open EPS files also (although they mention shady support for it on their documentations)

Comment: Hello @Onitlikesonic, welcome to GDSE. Software recommendations are a weird fit on our site. Although not  prohibited, they are not encouraged either, because the answers tend to go stale after a while (certainly in the free/open source world). See [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more info on what is on topic. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: "Surely such program must exist?" Well ... no. EPS (which is, by the way, a positively *ancient* format by now) can contain bitmap images and fonts – complete or subsetted. All data can be compressed. Data can be represented in a custom format, using custom Postscript code to display, or even generate, it. See for example [this maze generator](https://github.com/petdance/scraps/blob/master/maze.ps).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see this is an old question.  But it needs an answer I think.

Inkscape supports saving as EPS by default - out of the box. However, things such as Inkscape patterns, transparency, and effects are not supported in EPS.

Only use EPS for output. Your original work should be saved as SVG which is Inkscape's native file format. This will preserve everything for future editing purposes.

PDF is a much better alternative to EPS for outputting documents from Inkscape, whether you want it to be or not.

If you want to open an EPS in Inkscape on Windows you need to install [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html), and then you need to manually change your system path variables in Windows.

Comprehensive instructions appear on the [Inskcape website FAQs](https://inkscape.org/en/learn/faq/#how-open-eps-files-windows). There's even [a video tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tH6S-w5DAsY&feature=youtu.be) if you need more guidance. I have tested these instructions and they work with the latest version of Inkscape 0.92.3, and Ghostscript 9.23 for Windows (64 bit).

If I can do it, anyone can. It doesn't take someone with a PHD to do it.

When you have done it. Restart Inskcape.

When you open an EPS, you get a dialog like this. It shows up as PDF Import Settings, because that is what Inkscape/Ghostscript is doing. It's converting the EPS (PostScript) to a PDF.

[image]